# Board & Card Games Meetups

Tags: discussion

What is the consensus on organising B&CG themed physical meet-ups? Along the lines of [Barcamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BarCamp) or, indeed, [BoardGameCamps](http://lanyrd.com/2010/boardgamecamp/).

It might be a great way of promoting the site to a larger audience (and of course, at the very least, sharing favourite games).

I'm based in the South West U.K. - I'd be happy to organise one for my area.

Comment: Love the thought.  I'm unsure if we have enough active users now to get a quorum in any one place.  If you do get one going, we can probably insert a link into the site banner to promote it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to participate in a boardgames meetup.  I run a small weekly group in Victoria, BC, and used to run one in Seattle.  As the site grows, it would be wonderful for it to start putting members in touch with others in their area.

Boardgames are such a fundamentally social activity, it would be crazy for meetups not to happen!